# Moment generating function of Laplace distribution step by step

Tags: integration, moment-generating-functions

There are two similar posts but none of them helped me to get through the full derivation of the very simple MGF that should be according to Wikipedia:

$$
\frac {\exp(\mu t)}{1-b^{2}t^{2}}
$$

Here's my attempt:

Definition of MGF
$$
M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(t X)\right]
$$

by LOTUS

$$
= \int \exp(t x) \cdot p(x) dx
$$

Plugging-in PDF

$$
= \int \exp(t x) \cdot \frac{1}{2b}\exp \left(- \frac{\mid x - \mu \mid }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int \exp(t x) \cdot \exp \left(- \frac{\mid x - \mu \mid }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int \exp \left(t x - \frac{\mid x - \mu \mid }{b} \right) dx
$$

getting rid of abs. value

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(t x - \frac{ x - \mu  }{b} \right) dx
+ \frac{1}{2b} \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(t x - \frac{- x + \mu  }{b} \right) dx
$$

the left integral first

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{bt x - x - \mu  }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{bt x - x  }{b} \right) \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} \right) \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{bt x - x  }{b} \right)  dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} \right) \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  x \right)  dx
$$

Now since $\int e^{ax}\,dx={\frac {1}{a}}e^{ax}+C$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} \right) \cdot \left|  \frac{b}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  x \right)  \right|_{-\infty}^{\mu}
$$

Let's evaluate the integral first

$$
\left|  \frac{b}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  x \right) \right|_{-\infty}^{\mu}
$$

$$
= \frac{b}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  (\mu) \right) 
-
\frac{b}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  (-\infty)\right)
$$

Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} e^{-x} = 0$, the second term is 0

$$
= \frac{b}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  (\mu) \right) 
- 0
$$

---

Double check from WorlframAlpha:

$$
= \frac{b}{bt-1} \exp \left( \mu \left( t - \frac{1}{b} \right) \right)
$$

for $\frac{1}{b} < t$

---

Now the right-hand side integral:

$$
\frac{1}{2b} \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(t x - \frac{- x + \mu  }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
\frac{1}{2b} \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{b t x + x - \mu  }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{b t x + x   }{b} \right) \exp \left(\frac{-\mu  }{b} \right)dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ -\mu  }{b} \right) \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{b t x + x   }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ -\mu  }{b} \right) \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left( \frac{b t + 1 }{b} x\right) dx
$$

Now evaluate the integral

$$
\int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left( \frac{b t + 1 }{b} x\right) dx
$$

According to wolfram alpha

$$
= - \frac{b}{bt + 1}\exp\left(\mu \frac{1}{b + t}\right)
$$

for $\frac{1}{b} + t < 0$

Now sum-up these two integrals:

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} \right) \cdot \frac{b}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  (\mu) \right)  + \\
\frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ -\mu  }{b} \right) \cdot \left( - \frac{b}{bt + 1}\exp\left(\mu \frac{1}{b + t}\right) \right)
$$

And simplify

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} \right) \cdot \frac{b}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  (\mu) \right)  - \\
\frac{1}{2b} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ -\mu  }{b} \right) \cdot  \frac{b}{bt + 1} \cdot \exp\left(\mu \frac{1}{b + t}\right) 
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \cdot  \frac{b}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} \right) \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  (\mu) \right)  - \\
\frac{1}{2b} \cdot   \frac{b}{bt + 1} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ -\mu  }{b} \right) \cdot \exp\left(\mu \frac{1}{b + t}\right) 
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{b} \cdot  \frac{1}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} \right) \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  (\mu) \right)  - \\
\frac{1}{b} \cdot   \frac{1}{bt + 1} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ -\mu  }{b} \right) \cdot \exp\left(\mu \frac{1}{b + t}\right) 
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{b} \cdot  \frac{1}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left(\frac{- \mu  }{b} +\frac{ (bt  - 1)  }{b}  (\mu) \right)  - \\
\frac{1}{b} \cdot   \frac{1}{bt + 1} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ -\mu  }{b} + \mu \frac{1}{b + t}\right) 
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{b} \cdot  \frac{1}{ (bt  - 1)  } \cdot \exp \left( \mu \left(t - \frac{2}{b} \right) \right)  - \\
\frac{1}{b} \cdot   \frac{1}{bt + 1} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{ -\mu  }{b} + \mu \frac{1}{b + t}\right) 
$$

But I cannot move away from this ugly formula to the simple beauty. Is there just a stupid mistake above or am I doing something substantially wrong?

Comment: Could it be that when you got rid of the absolute value in the beginning that you mixed up the integral limits? So if you take the integral from $-\infty$ to $\mu$, then $|x-\mu|=-x+\mu$ and the opposite in the other integral?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, yes, there is indeed a mistake and it definitely helped me to move forward!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101653/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's the full correct solution if anyone is interested.

Definition of MGF
$$
M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(t X)\right]
$$

by LOTUS

$$
= \int \exp(t x) \cdot p(x) dx
$$

Plugging-in PDF

$$
= \int \exp(t x) \cdot \frac{1}{2b}\exp \left(- \frac{\mid x - \mu \mid }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int \exp(t x) \cdot \exp \left(- \frac{\mid x - \mu \mid }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int \exp \left(t x - \frac{\mid x - \mu \mid }{b} \right) dx
$$

For integrating absolute value, we split the integral at $\mu$, such that it change the absolute values to

- for $x < \mu$: $\mid x - \mu \mid = -(x - \mu)$
- for $x \geq \mu$: $\mid x - \mu \mid = x - \mu$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(t x - \frac{-(x - \mu) }{b} \right) dx +
\frac{1}{2b} \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(t x - \frac{x - \mu}{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{b t x + x - \mu }{b} \right) dx +
\int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{btx - x + \mu}{b} \right) dx \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \left(  \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{b t x + x - \mu }{b} \right) dx +
\int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{btx - x + \mu}{b} \right) dx \right)
$$

Let's solve the left-hand side integral first

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{b t x + x - \mu }{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{-\mu}{b} \right) \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{b t x + x}{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{-\mu}{b} \right) \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{x (b t + 1)}{b} \right) dx
$$

Now since $\int e^{ax}\,dx={\frac {1}{a}}e^{ax}+C$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{-\mu}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt + 1} \left| \exp \left(\frac{x (b t + 1)}{b} \right) \right|_{-\infty}^{\mu}
$$

When evaluating for $-\infty$, we need to have this limit converge:

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} \exp \left(x \frac{(b t + 1)}{b} \right)
$$

The constants have to be positive, so

$$
\frac{(b t + 1)}{b} > 0 \\
t > -\frac{1}{b}
$$

So let's evaluate and move on

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{-\mu}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt + 1} \left( \exp \left(\frac{\mu (b t + 1)}{b} \right) - 0 \right)
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{-\mu + \mu (b t + 1)}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt + 1} 
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{-\mu + \mu b t + \mu}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt + 1} 
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{\mu b t}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt + 1} 
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \mu  t \right) \frac{b}{bt + 1} 
$$

Now the right-hand side integral:

$$
\int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{btx - x + \mu}{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{\mu}{b} \right) \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{btx - x}{b} \right) dx
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{\mu}{b} \right) \int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{x(bt - 1)}{b} \right) dx
$$

And again since $\int e^{ax}\,dx={\frac {1}{a}}e^{ax}+C$

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{\mu}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt - 1} \left| \exp \left(\frac{x(bt - 1)}{b} \right) \right|_{\mu}^{\infty}
$$

Again, for the integral to converge, we need to make sure that this goes to zero

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \exp \left(x \frac{(b t - 1)}{b} \right)
$$

So the constant have to be negative such that

$$
\frac{(b t - 1)}{b} < 0 \\
t < \frac{1}{b}
$$

Let's evalate and move on

$$
= \exp \left( \frac{\mu}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt - 1} \left( 0 -\exp \left(\frac{\mu(bt - 1)}{b} \right)  \right)
$$

$$
= - \exp \left( \frac{\mu}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt - 1} \exp \left(\frac{\mu(bt - 1)}{b} \right)
$$

$$
= - \exp \left( \frac{\mu}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt - 1} \exp \left(\frac{\mu bt - \mu)}{b} \right)
$$

$$
= - \exp \left( \frac{\mu + \mu bt - \mu}{b} \right) \frac{b}{bt - 1}
$$

$$
= - \exp \left( \mu t  \right) \frac{b}{bt - 1}
$$

Now plug these two results in the original equation

$$
\frac{1}{2b} \left(  \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \exp \left(\frac{b t x + x - \mu }{b} \right) dx +
\int_{\mu}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{btx - x + \mu}{b} \right) dx \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \left(  \exp \left( \mu  t \right) \frac{b}{bt + 1} 
- \exp \left( \mu t  \right) \frac{b}{bt - 1} \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2b} \exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{b}{bt + 1} 
-  \frac{b}{bt - 1} \right)
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{b}{2b(bt + 1)} 
-  \frac{b}{2b(bt - 1)} \right)
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{1}{2(bt + 1)} 
-  \frac{1}{2(bt - 1)} \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2 }\exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{1}{bt + 1} 
-  \frac{1}{bt - 1} \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2 }\exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{(bt - 1) - (bt + 1)}{b^2 t^2 - 1}  \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2 }\exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{bt - 1 - bt - 1)}{b^2 t^2 - 1}  \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2 }\exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{- 2}{b^2 t^2 - 1}  \right)
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{- 1}{b^2 t^2 - 1}  \right)
$$

$$
= \exp \left( \mu t  \right) \left(   \frac{1}{- b^2 t^2 + 1}  \right)
$$

$$
=     \frac{\exp ( \mu t  )}{1 - b^2 t^2} \qquad \square
$$

for $t < \frac{1}{b}$ and  $t > -\frac{1}{b}$, which we can rewrite as $t < \frac{1}{b}$ and  $- t < \frac{1}{b}$ and thus simplify to $|t| < \frac{1}{b}$.

Comment: very well done!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of efficiencies that can be realized if we first consider the shifted exponential family $$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{b} e^{-(y - \mu)/b}, \quad y \ge \mu$$ with location $\mu$ and scale $b > 0$.  The MGF is easy to calculate:  $$M_Y(t) = \int_{y=\mu}^\infty \frac{1}{b} e^{ty} e^{-y/b} e^{\mu/b} \, dy = \frac{e^{\mu/b}}{b} \int_{y=\mu}^\infty e^{-(1/b-t)y} \, dy = \frac{e^{\mu/b} e^{-(1/b - t)\mu}}{b(1/b-t)} = \frac{e^{\mu t}}{1 - bt} , \quad t < 1/b.$$  The MGF of $-Y$ is then $$M_{-Y}(t) = M_Y(-t) = \frac{e^{-\mu t}}{1 + bt}, \quad t > -1/b.$$
Now define the mixture density $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2} (f_{Y_1}(x) + f_{-Y_2}(x))$$ where $Y_1$ is shifted with location $\mu$, and $Y_2$ is shifted with location $-\mu$, and both share scale $b$.  Then it is easy to see $X$ is Laplace with location $\mu$ and scale $b$.  The MGF of $X$ is then $$M_X(t) = \frac{1}{2} \left( M_{Y_1}(t) + M_{-Y_2}(t) \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{e^{\mu t}}{1 - bt} + \frac{e^{-(-\mu)t}}{1 + bt} \right) = \frac{e^{\mu t}}{1 - (bt)^2}, \quad |t| < 1/b.$$

In fact, this computation easily generalizes to the case where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ do not have the same scale parameter, in which the distribution has nonzero skew.

Comment: Nice approach. So basically you first re-define Laplace as a mixture of two exponential distributions, and for those it's straightforward to integrate the MGF.

Comment: @JohnDoe Correct.  The key insight is to note that the MGF of a mixture is the sum of the MGFs of its component densities, thus for a distribution that is in a sense a piecewise sum of simpler distributions from the same parametric family, we save some duplication of computations, and in this instance, also avoid dealing with casework that arises from the distribution being described with absolute values.

Comment: Very good insights, thank you.