# Getting moment generating function for a pdf, integration limits?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

I am working on a problem that I always believed I understood how to do but I cannot seem to get the correct answer. I am given the pdf
$f(x) = .5e^{-|x|}$ for x from negative infinity to infinity. I am supposed to be showing that the Moment generating function is
$M(t)=1/{(1-t^2)}$ for $|t|<1$

So i already know what the answer is supposed to be but I cannot seem to get there so I am wondering if I am misunderstanding something

The moment Generating function is $E(e^{tX})$  so it would be $\int e^{tx}.5e^{|x|}$  correct?

I simplied this to $.5\int e^{tx-|x|}$ Then took the antiderivative

I have calculated this out to be $.5(1/t-1)e^{tx-|x|}$

I have never been great with derivates and integral of $e$ so if this is where all of my problems lie that would not be surprised but if it is wrong if someone could walk through it that would be amazing.

I am slightly confused on if the limits of the integral are negative infinity to infinity or from 0 to 1 since that is the limit of t. Either way I do not get the correct answer

I am either having issues with my integral or just my general understanding, any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101653/what-is-the-moment-generating-function-of-the-laplace-distribution and take $\lambda=1$ and $\mu=0$. Note that you need to have a negative in the exponent otherwise $f$ is not a valid density

Comment: @WeakLearner I did mean to have a negative thank you

Comment: For $x \li 0$, contribution should have 1/(t+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking the indefinite integral, while it should be the definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Once you set the integral limits, your only problem is $|x|$, which can be solved by breaking up the integral when $x<0$ and $x>0$.